# How to use bitwise operators in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to python. I have tested my interpreter using following code,

```
In [1]: 2 and 3
Out[1]: 3

In [2]: 3 and 2
Out[2]: 2

In [3]: 3 or 2
Out[3]: 3

In [4]: 2 or 3
Out[4]: 2
```

In the above, take `2=0010` and `3=0011`. the result is,

```
+ 0010
  0011
  ----
  0010=2
```

But `Out[1]` gave the 3(not exact) and `out[2]` gave the 2(exact).

What is the difference in two cases?

Comment: usually people mix it up the other way around

Answer (score 10):

You are using [boolean logic `or` and `and`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations), which short-circuit (return the first operand for which the outcome of the operator is fixed).

You are looking for the [binary bitwise operators](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations) instead, `|` and `&`:

```
>>> 0b10 & 0b1
0
>>> 0b10 | 0b1
3
```

The `or` operator returns the first operand if it is true-y (not empty or numeric 0), the second operand otherwise, the `and` operator returns the first if it is false-y, the second operator otherwise. This is why you see `3 and 2` return `2`, and `3 or 2` return `3`. Both `2` and `3` are non-zero, so true in a boolean context.

Using `0` as a false value you'd see:

```
>>> 3 and 0
0
>>> 3 or 0
3
>>> 0 and 3
0
>>> 0 or 3
3
```

Comment: In python, a few values are considered to be "false": `False`, `None`, `0`, and any object `obj` where `len(obj)==0`, for example `""`, `[]`, `()` and `{}`.  All other objects are considered to be "true". Here are a few examples using the logical operators: `[] or 5 == 5`, `[] or () == ()`, `True and None == None`, `[1,2,3] or False == [1,2,3]`, etc.

Comment: @MiniQuark: Apart from `None` they can all be reduced to 'empty' or 'numeric 0'.

Comment: you're right, but I wanted to spell it out because it's not trivial that `int(False)==0` and `int(None)==0`.  The precise rules are available here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing

Comment: @MiniQuark: `int(None)` is just the `int()` constructor with no argument; `True == 1` is `True`, as is `False == 0`, but `None == 0` is `False`. That's because the `bool` type is a subclass of `int`.

Comment: @MiniQuark: And I am focusing here on the bitwise operators with a brief explanation as to why the OP got confused. There is no need to go into the nitty gritty details of what makes something falsey or truey, the documentation I link to contains that detail for someone that wants to know more.

Answer (score 6):

You are looking for the bitwise operators,

```
>>> 2 & 3
2
>>> 2 | 3
3
```

By just doing `2 and 3` you are evaluating `2`, which is `True`, then `3` (also `True`) and Python returns that second number. So you get `3`.

With `2 or 3`, it short-circuits and just returns `2` since `2` is `True`.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the bitwise and, `&`.

`and` and `or` are boolean operators in Python, whereas `&` and `|` are bitwise operators.

Example -

```
>>> 2 and 3
3
>>> 2 & 3
2
```

Answer (score 1):

use `&`,  `and` is boolean `AND` in python:

```
>>> 2 & 3
2
>>> 3 & 2
2
```